# Selecting a file with gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

Below is an artificial example of a R widget created with the gWidgets package:

```
library(gWidgets)
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")

f <- function(file){
    dat <- read.table(file, header=TRUE)
return(dat[1,])
}

lst <- list() 
    lst$action <- list(beginning="f(",ending=")")
    lst$arguments$file <- list(type="gfilebrowse")

ggenericwidget(lst, container=gwindow("Example"))
```

Using Windows there is a problem when browsing and selecting the file: the backslashes are not doubled in the file path. How to overcome this problem ? I don'y know how to replace the backslashes with double backslashes in a character string.

Answer (score -1):

You might want `gsub("/", "\\\\", x)` but am not sure it is needed. I don't have a windows machine ready to test, but I'd be surprised if this was needed.

Comment: I think it is not possible to transform "C:\myfile.txt" to "C:\\myfile.txt", simply because "C:\myfile.txt" is not a valid chain character.